# In React, how do you use propTypes to check the properties of an object?

Tags: reactjs

I am passing props to a component in this way:

```
let obj = {
    id: someId,
    name: someName
}; 

<SomeComponent obj={obj} />
```

I want to be able to use `propTypes` to check the props entering into `SomeComponent`, for example:

```
SomeComponent.propTypes = {
    obj.id: PropTypes.number,
    obj.name: PropTypes.string
};
```

but the above syntax is not accepted - how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PropTypes.shape for this purpose.

```
SomeComponent.propTypes = {
    obj : React.Proptypes.shape({
       id: React.PropTypes.number,
       name: React.PropTypes.string
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
SomeComponent.propTypes = {
    obj: React.PropTypes.shape({
       id: PropTypes.number,
       name: PropTypes.name
    })
};
```